# How to create excel file in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I am very new to asp.net development

I have presented the user to download the  `asp repeater grid details` in excel format on button click. I have done it with following code which  I got after googling

```
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=ExcelExport.xls");

            for (int i = 0; i < RptMasterData.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                Table tbl = (Table)RptMasterData.Items[i].FindControl("tblTest");
                tbl.Style.Add("background-color", "#FF9900");
                GridView gvAllocation = (GridView)RptMasterData.Items[i].FindControl("gvAllocation");
                gvAllocation.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#95c556");

                int j = 1;
                foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in gvAllocation.Rows)
                {
                    gvAllocation.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                    if (j <= gvAllocation.Rows.Count)
                    {
                        if (j % 2 != 0)
                        {
                            for (int k = 0; k < gvrow.Cells.Count; k++)
                            {
                                gvrow.Cells[k].Style.Add("background-color", "#EFF3FB");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    j++;
                }
            }

            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
            Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());

            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

            //style to format numbers to string
            string style = @"<style> .textmode { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>";
            Response.Write(style);
            RptMasterData.RenderControl(hw);
            Response.Write("<table>");
            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.Write("<table>");
            Response.Flush();
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
            Response.Close();
```

The file is downloaded as excel file.But when I try to open the file in MS office I get the Error message as

[image]

The problem occurred when I try to edit and save the file in Ms-office. then it shows following warning
[image]

So I Just tried to open the same in text editor and found that the file downloaded is an HTML file containing the needed data as expected not excel file.

Can anyone guide me in how to create an actual Excel file for downloading when user click "Download"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codeplex EPPlus http://epplus.codeplex.com/  is Good liberary to create Spreadsheet document in the server